# Конвертер работает не корректно

Tags: java

Я написал конвертер который конвертирует кириллицу в казахскую латиницу. И он его конвертирует, но в добавок он еще конвертирует латинскую английскую в латиницу казахскую. Как сделать так чтобы он только кириллицу переводила в латиницу.

Я написал код где может быть ошибка

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws  IOException {
        final String DEFAULT_ENCODING = "utf-8";

        if(args.length < 2 || args.length > 3) {
            System.out.println("Неверное количество аргументов");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String inputFilePath = args[0];
        String outputFilePath = args[1];    
        String fileEncoding = args.length == 2 ? DEFAULT_ENCODING : args[2];

        //FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFilePath);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFilePath), fileEncoding));
        File file = new File(outputFilePath);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, false);

        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        String line;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        Map<String, String> dictionary = new Dictionary().getDictionary();

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String outLine = convertString(line, dictionary) + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println(outLine);
            result.append(outLine) ;
        }

        writer.write(result.toString());

        in.close();
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        //fileReader.close();        
    }


    public static String convertString(String str, Map<String, String> dictionary) {
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (dictionary.containsKey(Character.toString(chars[i]))) {
                stringBuilder.append(dictionary.get(Character.toString(chars[i])));
                continue;
            }
            stringBuilder.append(chars[i]);
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}

class Dictionary {
    private Map<String, String> dictionary;

    public Dictionary() {
        dictionary = new HashMap<>();
        dictionary = new HashMap<>();
        dictionary.put("а", "a");
        dictionary.put("А", "А");
        dictionary.put("ә", "á");
        dictionary.put("Ә", "Á");
        dictionary.put("б", "b");
        dictionary.put("Б", "B");
        dictionary.put("д", "d");
        dictionary.put("Д", "D");
        dictionary.put("е", "e");
        dictionary.put("E", "E");
        dictionary.put("ф", "f");
        dictionary.put("Ф", "F");
        dictionary.put("г", "g");
        dictionary.put("Г", "G");
        dictionary.put("ғ", "ǵ");
        dictionary.put("Ғ", "Ǵ");        
        dictionary.put("х", "h");
        dictionary.put("Х", "H");
        dictionary.put("h", "һ");
        dictionary.put("Һ", "Һ");
        dictionary.put("і", "i");
        dictionary.put("І", "І");
        dictionary.put("и", "ı");
        dictionary.put("И", "I");
        dictionary.put("й", "i");
        dictionary.put("Й", "I");
        dictionary.put("ж", "j");
        dictionary.put("Ж", "J");
        dictionary.put("к", "k");
        dictionary.put("К", "К");
        dictionary.put("л", "l");
        dictionary.put("Л", "L");
        dictionary.put("м", "m");
        dictionary.put("М", "M");
        dictionary.put("н", "n");
        dictionary.put("Н", "N");
        dictionary.put("ң", "ń");
        dictionary.put("Ң", "Ń");
        dictionary.put("о", "o");
        dictionary.put("О", "О");
        dictionary.put("ө", "ó");
        dictionary.put("Ө", "Ó");
        dictionary.put("п", "p");
        dictionary.put("П", "P");
        dictionary.put("қ", "q");
        dictionary.put("Қ", "Q");
        dictionary.put("р", "r");
        dictionary.put("Р", "R");
        dictionary.put("с", "s");
        dictionary.put("С", "S");
        dictionary.put("ш", "sh");
        dictionary.put("Ш", "Sh");
        dictionary.put("ч", "ch");
        dictionary.put("Ч", "Сh");
        dictionary.put("т", "t");
        dictionary.put("Т", "T");
        dictionary.put("ү", "ú");
        dictionary.put("Ү", "Ú");
        dictionary.put("ұ", "u");
        dictionary.put("Ұ", "U");
        dictionary.put("в", "v");
        dictionary.put("В", "V");
        dictionary.put("ы", "y");
        dictionary.put("Ы", "Y");
        dictionary.put("у", "ý");
        dictionary.put("У", "Ý");
        dictionary.put("з", "z");
        dictionary.put("З", "Z");
        dictionary.put("э", "e");
        dictionary.put("Э", "E");
        dictionary.put("ю", "ıý");
        dictionary.put("Ю", "Iý");
        dictionary.put("я", "ıa");
        dictionary.put("Я", "Ia");

    }

    public Map<String, String> getDictionary() {
        return dictionary;

    }
}
```

Comment: В цикле `for` добавьте `else`.

Comment: Никак. Вы с точки зрения зрения джавы между казахским f и латинским f нет никакой разницы, можно написать эвристику которая будет смотреть на соседние буквы. Похоже для в уникоде нет специального энтрипойнта для казахского f.

Comment: Я хочу перевести слово компьютер на латинский. Он должен выдать - kompıýter, а почему конвертирует вот так  с мягким знаком - kompьıýter. Как можно исправить ошибку